# Could Dr. Shaw have run around like that immediately after her Caesarean-Section?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

Wouldn't the muscles that had just been sliced through and stapled back together inhibit her movements? She slid right out of the med-pod, and ran around. Wouldn't this have physically impossible to use the muscles that had been cut?

I know she took painkillers but those would simply deaden the pain. That's different from being able to use those muscles to that extent.

Comment: I think this is one of the many little plot holes in *Prometheus* ... I see you must be watching it on TV at the moment ... my wife is doing the same, lol.

Comment: @Paulster2 Yeah, I've watched twice in 2 days now, lol.

Comment: Is it clear from the scene that the staples are the only thing holding them together, or is it possible there is some additional futuristic technology used to "glue" the cut muscle surfaces? Also, given that there are motor nerves connected to muscle fibers on either end of the cut, would it actually be necessary for biochemical signals to travel across the cut in order for parts of the muscle on either side to contract and relax in synch?

Answer (score 3):

### Yes.

Although doing stomach-crunches and playing volleyball are probably out, even after a ***21st Century c-section***, with sufficient painkillers and sufficient motivation, a woman could almost certainly be able to do all of the things seen in the film, specifically running, crouching and yelling. Obviously she'd then suffer the consequences in the long-term (post-op trauma, bruising, permanent muscle damage). Taking into account any medical advances over the next 200+ years, I think we can be reasonably sure that her actions were *medically ill-advised* but not actually impossible.

---

The [earlier version of the script](https://archive.org/stream/pdfy-9NMTSgzvy2U3U-oz/Alien-Engineers-ORIGINAL-PROMETHEUS-SCRIPT_djvu.txt) indicates that her injuries (and subsequent recovery) are nothing short of miraculous. Under the circumstances, the fact that she's not **dead** should be the major concern rather than her ability to sprint :-)

> In the pod, scanning beams and sensors probe Watts’s horrific wound. A
>   nightmare list scrolls across the pod’s screen:
>
> COLLAPSED LEFT LUNG
>
> PUNCTURED RIGHT VENTRICLE
>
> PERFORATED STOMACH
>
> RUPTURED SPLEEN
>
> GROSS MUSCULAR TRAUMA...
>
> Manipulators plunge lines into her veins - recharging her body with
>   artificial blood. An oxygen tube slips down her throat. An epidural
>   into her spine.

Comment: Ok, I had no idea she suffered these things too, I assume they are from the alien inside her, correct? The last sentence did not happen in the movie, or did I miss it?

Comment: @joshschwarzzeskywalker - They seem to have decided to make the chest - burster into more of a egg with tentacles

Comment: "One thing that people are all disturbed about is sex... I said 'That's how I'm going to attack the audience; I'm going to attack them sexually. And I'm not going to go after the women in the audience, I'm going to attack the men. I am going to put in every image I can think of to make the men in the audience cross their legs. Homosexual oral rape, birth. The thing lays its eggs down your throat, the whole number.'"  http://www.cracked.com/article_18932_alien-film-franchise-based-entirely-rape.html